# API for dynamic validation, configurable using XML or properties file

Tags: java, validation

I'm about to embark on a project for data migration. (Lotus notes to Oracle DB)

It requires a lot of validation.

The flow goes like this

-> Read translate to OBJECTS -> VALIDATIONS -> Insert into database.

I'm considering of doing for validation to make it configurable via XML or properties file.

Once the objects are translated, it will look into xml/text file and retrieve the validation for each fields. 
I assume different type of validation will be command objects.

and XML will contain the command object to call.

For example...

validating a object report contain title, product.

During validation it will look into XML and validate the fields. When I need to add in different type of validation, I merely need to code the command object and change the xml.

This will enhance re-usability and configuration.

Summary:

Are there any APIs I can use? I am looking into hibernate validator.

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

how can I store the structure of the validation in the xml? It seems like I need to use reflections too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.????